# Удаление пробела в строке в javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярное выражение:

```
^[а-яё?\s]+$
```

Как дополнить эту регулярку, чтобы в начале и в конце обрезались пробелы, а внутри слова пробел допускался?
Т.е "Иван Иванов" - пропускаем, "Иван Иванов " - не пропускаем?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать `trim()`? Приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает.

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно разложить символьный класс на группы/"атомы", попробуйте `/^[а-яё?]+(?:\s[а-яё?]+)*$/i`

Comment: _Т.е "Иван Иванов" - пропускаем, "Иван Иванов " - не пропускаем?_ - текущее регулярное выражение похоже именно так и работает

Comment: @Grundy, Пробел в конце строки и в начале матчится.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, ваша регулярка подходит, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю разобрать символьный класс на пробелы и всё остальное и сложить такое выражение:

```
/^[а-яё?]+(?:\s+[а-яё?]+)*$/i
```

или (если разрешен только 1 пробел между словами):

```
/^[а-яё?]+(?:\s[а-яё?]+)*$/i
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/3V8ua3/2).

Оно найдёт:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[а-яё?]+` - 1 и более русских букв
- `(?:\s[а-яё?]+)*` - 0 и более:

  - `\s+` - 1 и более пробелов (удалите `+`, *если разрешен только 1 пробел* между словами)
  - `[а-яё?]+` - 1 и более русских букв
- `$`  - конец строки

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
^(?:[^ ][а-яё?\s]+[^ ]?|[^ ]?[а-яё?\s]+[^ ])$
```

Comment: В конце строки матчится пробел

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать на вопрос, то так

```
^[^\s][а-яё?\s]*[^\s]$
```

Но может лучше вызвать `trim()`?

Comment: `[а-яё?\s]+?` - это ошибка, по-моему

Comment: @Yuri: Нет, не ошибка (`+?` - это ленивый квантификатор `+`), но так как и у вас требует наличия в строке как минимум 2 символов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew На счет двух символов Вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: Ой, на самом деле были обязательны 3 символа в строке. Теперь обязательно наличие 2-х символов. `[^\s]` требует наличие символа. Но это, я думаю, не так актуально. Кстати, ленивый квантификатор тут не к месту, только тормозит движок.

Comment: @V.Manokhin, регулярка из этого ответа вполне пропустит такую строку `<>`. Тест https://regex101.com/r/b7OZfd/1

Answer (score 0):

Используйте .trim(); Оригинальную строку не изменяет. Поддерживается везде.

```
var str = " temp ";
str.trim();
```

Есть еще:

```
jQuery.trim();
```